# How can I change my API link with a date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Currently my api link is dynamic by selecting the current year and month.

Example:
APILINK.../202109

That part is fine... But what I want to do is change the last part of the API link (Year and Month) with a datepicker and I'm not sure how I can do that.

My current Code:

```
const timehsheetUrl = "API LINK"
const today = new Date();
const date = today.getFullYear()+('0' + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
const settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": timesleetUrl + date,
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {}
}
```

Comment: Which datepicker are you using?

Comment: @MukeshSinghThakur Currently the default HTML <input type="date"/> date picker. But I'm assuming if I want to just have the year and month it has to be a custom date picker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to use datepicker plugin, while plugin is more convenient.

Here's an example with default HTML date-input.

```js
const timesleetUrl = "API LINK";
const today = new Date();
function urlDateSuffix(_date) {
  return  _date.getFullYear()+('0' + (_date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
}

let settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": timesleetUrl + urlDateSuffix(today),
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {}
}
console.log(settings);

$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').change(function() {
    settings.url = timesleetUrl + urlDateSuffix(new Date(this.value));
    console.log(settings);
    alert(settings.url);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="datepicker">
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the link once the html page has been loaded?
Because your code works perfectly but the problem is that the content isn't changing but it is logging it.

Comment: @Gabe On the initialization part - `let settings = {...}` - `settings.url` would be inited with `timesleetUrl + urlDateSuffix(today)` :)

Comment: Oh sorry let me correct myself. What I mean is that The link is successfully changing but I am using Apex Charts with this function. So I am not sure why after the content is loaded the first time I cannot update the charts that has rendered already.

Comment: @Gabe `document.onload = function(){...}` can be the first chance to change initial url. For your case, I'm not sure how did you write code for ApexChart, but in my experience, the method for dataset refresh would be exists.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy use jQuery date picker.

On date select script should return selected date's month and year.

Store the output in variable and format. The code shown below will help you

```
// html markup, use jQuery UI CDN in head section
<input type="text" id="calendar" name="date1"/>
// html markup

<script>
$('#calendar').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-m-d',
    inline: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
            day  = date.getDate(),  
            month = date.getMonth() + 1,              
            year =  date.getFullYear();
         // alert(day + '-' + month + '-' + year);
         // this is your result
         alert( "api link is   "+"APILINK.../"+year+month);
    }
});
</script>
```